# How to match only the beginning of a field using query filtering in Laravel

Tags: laravel, filter

I have a query param from the URL `q`, for this example let's say it's `foo`. This needs to be used to filter either the `name`, `surname`, or `email` of a `User` record.

But partial matches should only be returned if they match the beginning of at least one of those fields.

e.g a User with name `oofoo` should not be returned. I think this is a regex issue.

I'm using Eloquent `orWhere()`:

```
return $this->model->where("id", $blahblahId)
    ->firstOrFail()
    ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $queryParam . '%')
    ->orWhere('surname', 'like', '%' . $queryParam . '%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $queryParam . '%')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have % only at end. Is is not Laravel issue, its just SQL

- %xxx% - column has somewhere "xxx" inside (can be also beginning, end and exact "xxx")
- %xxx - column ends with "xxx"
- xxx% - column starts with "xxx"

So in your case it will be:

```
return $this->model->where("id", $blahblahId)
    ->firstOrFail()
    ->where('name', 'like', $queryParam . '%')
    ->orWhere('surname', 'like', $queryParam . '%')
    ->orWhere('email', 'like', $queryParam . '%')
    ->get();
```

Read more https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp